# What is the iPhone retina and non-retina display tab bar icon actual size

Tags: iphone, resolution

Can anyone suggest me the actual sizes for iPhone's tab bar icon, retina as well as non-retina?

I tried with 120x120px for retina and 72x72 for non-retina, but it's not going with that.

Answer (score 0):

Tab bar:

30px - Non Retina
60px - Retina

For a full list of all icon sizes for both displays: 
http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/ios/

Answer (score 0):

Here, Refer these : [tabBar Icon Size](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html)
and [Tabbar Icon Size](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html)